# How can I achieve such layout in LaTeX (memoir)?

Tags: memoir, layout

[image: The attachment is a snapshot of an e-book.]

Before "Exercise 1.2", the page has 'margin note' and 'body' on its own but after that, the 'body' seems to have merged with the 'margin note'. I want to have the similar layout on my book.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{memoir}
\setstocksize{10in}{8.5in}
\setpageml{0.9\stockheight}{0.9\stockwidth}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1in}{2in}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{0.75in}{0.75in}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout[fixed]

\usepackage[]{showframe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xsim}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem Ipsum}
\lipsum[1]

\marginparmargin{outer}
\marginpar{%
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}}

\begin{exercise}    %   this environment needs to typeset throughout the paper width
\lipsum[2]
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of MWE]

Comment: You could use memoir's `adjustwidth` environment for the pre-exercise text, or try the `wrapfig` package.

Comment: Thank you, @PeterWilson! `adjustwidth` environment did the job.